# Switching Ribbon and Navigation Bar Location, MySites

Tags: my-site, navigation, css, feature-stapling

I'm trying to get the Top Navigation Bar (My Site, My Content, My Profile...) to go below the Top Ribbon. Basically I want the top area of MySites to look just like a regular site collection. Any idea how to do this? Right now I've managed to switch the two bars location so he Ribbon is at the top and the Navigation Bar is below but the content of page still moves with the ribbon and therefore it covers the Navigation bar when the ribbon is expanded. How can I fix this? This is my code for switching the order of the two:

```
body #s4-ribbonrow 
{
    background-color:black;
    width: 1041px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    position: relative;
    top: -44px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.ms-globalnav {
    background-color: black !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    height: 43px !important;
    width: 1041px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 133px;
}
```

And how would I go about having the same area open when the Ribbon is hidden so I can have a logo there? I am using feature stapling to modify CSS and branding but I can't seem to make this top area of the MySites look like the regular site collections.

EDIT: Some more info + Screenshots
Basically this is what happens: 
http://i828.photobucket.com/albums/zz208/TooT3R/whathappens.png

Where the top nav bar (My Site, My Profile...) is under the content since it moved up due to the ribbon being hidden.

And this is what I want, even when the ribbon is hidden, should show a logo or something.
http://i828.photobucket.com/albums/zz208/TooT3R/whatiwant.png

***sorry about the images, I don't have the reputation to be able to embed them so I just posted the links.

Thanks for any help!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out as well. I added the code (entire control code) for the navigation bar that is on all other sites to the My Sites as well. I got this from the v4.master masterpage.

I then hid the navigation bar that My Sites has in my CSS and styled the new control (the one I added) according to my my other sites. I had to create a sitemap for this new control so that I would have the same links as the other SharePoint sites. Now I have a cross site collection/web application navigation interface and it meets my needs!

Hopefully this helps someone, if more details are needed I can provide some code but like I said its all from within the v4.master and then creating a site map.

As for moving the ribbon above the navigation bar, I simply used position:relative to move the two.

PS: I also used code from the v4.master (simply copy and paste into custom masterpage) to bring back the 'header' that shows up when the ribbon is hidden and user is on 'Browse' tab.